# MySQL query returning sum of a joined column

Tags: mysql

When I run the following query, it returns 9 records as it should.

```
Select
 snpc_stats.gamedetail.Finish As Rank,
 snpc_stats.gamedetail.Player As Player,
(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Points + snpc_stats.gamedetail.Hits) As Points,
snpc_stats.gamedetail.RoundOut As `Round Out`,
snpc_stats.gamedetail.Hits As Hits,
snpc_stats.gamedetail.Points As `Game Points`,
snpc_stats.gamedetail.Hitman As Hitman,
snpc_stats.gamedetail.TimeOut As `Time Out`,
snpc_stats.games.BuyIn As `Buy In`,
snpc_stats.gamedetail.ChampFund As `Champ Fund`,
snpc_stats.gamedetail.Winnings As Winnings,
(replace(replace(snpc_stats.gamedetail.Winnings, '$', ''), ',', '') -
 replace(replace(snpc_stats.games.BuyIn, '$', ''), ',', '') -
 replace(replace(snpc_stats.gamedetail.ChampFund, '$', ''), ',', '')) As Net,
snpc_stats.games.Round,
snpc_stats.games.GameDate,
snpc_stats.games.Location

From
snpc_stats.gamedetail Inner Join
snpc_stats.games On snpc_stats.games.GameID = snpc_stats.gamedetail.GamesID

Where
snpc_stats.gamedetail.GamesID = 113
```

When I try to add the following to the end of the SELECT it only returns 1 record

```
, SUM(replace(replace(snpc_stats.games.BuyIn, '$', ''), ',', '')) As Purse
```

The Winnings, Buyin, and ChampFund are VARCHAR dataype. I know they should be INT but someone else made the db originally...

If someone could help me figure out how to return all 9 records while Totaling the "BuyIn" column, I would be grateful! It' close.

Comment: If you have an aggegrate function in the select clause and no group by, grouping is done over the whole table, the value of the non aggreate columns is inpredictable, so you should add a group_by clause.

Comment: The fact that someone else chose the wrong datatype doesn't mean you can't correct it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SUM sentence is an aggregated functions, that means, it will add all the rows returned, that's why you are getting only one row:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

If you wanted add by some properties, you will have to add the SUM() in your filed definition, and a GROUP BY clause at the end of your query, and specify the fields you're grouping by. Something like:

```
GROUP BY player [, more fields you wanted to group by]
```